# How do I get a list of all subdomains of a domain?

Tags: dns, subdomain, dig, nameservers

I want to find out all the subdomains of a given domain. I found a hint which tells me to dig the authoritative nameserver with the following option:

```bash
dig @ns1.foo.example example.com axfr
```

But this never works. Has anyone a better idea/approach?

Comment: Also see here for an updated list of tools: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/35078/18541

Comment: site:*.meteor.com/ -site:www.meteor.com

Comment: I wish there were a stack exchange just to learn from each other the best ways to get information out of the Internet.Thanks @DipeshKc

Comment: pentest-tools.com/reconnaissance/find-subdomains-of-domain

Comment: [http://archive.is/*.example.com](http://archive.is/*.example.com) might help you out.

Comment: https://crt.sh/?q=%25.domain.com for ssl-protected subdomains.

Comment: Some of the answers here point to major search engines, but you could also use commoncrawl.org WARC files. Some of their [tutorials](http://commoncrawl.org/the-data/tutorials/) explain how the search engines look at an entire internet full of addresses and find things, from which you might be able to back out an approach (and therefore modify / script it, versus just “rely on google”).  HTH.

Comment: If you are PDNS administrator, you can enable AXFR requests, or `pdnsutil list-zone example.com`. Of course this will work only if you are host these domains.

Comment: There's a tool for that. It will only list the first 10 or so domains for free. Premium after that. https://subdomains.whoisxmlapi.com/

Answer (score 165, accepted):

The hint (using axfr) only works if the NS you're querying (`ns1.foo.example` in your example) is configured to allow AXFR requests from the IP you're using; this is unlikely, unless your IP is configured as a secondary for the domain in question.

Basically, there's no easy way to do it if you're not allowed to use axfr. This is intentional, so the only way around it would be via brute force (i.e. `dig a.example.com`, `dig b.example.com`, ...), which I can't recommend, as it could be viewed as a denial of service attack.

Comment: Correct command should be: dig @123.456.789.123 DOMAIN.COM -t axfr

Comment: Netcraft solution: http://searchdns.netcraft.com/?restriction=site+contains&host=stackoverflow.com

Comment: I tried every answer on this page and nothing worked.  The question is protected so I can't add another answer, but the tool on this site was the only thing that worked for me: https://pentest-tools.com/reconnaissance/find-subdomains-of-domain

Comment: @ACK_stoverflow   -  That tells me I have 4 subdomains , when I know there are over 100

Comment: How can we check if a domain supports AXFR requests?

Comment: @steven-m-vascellaro Per the answer from @victor-klos below, using ```host -l mydomain.com``` will fail with ```Transfer failed``` if AXFR is not supported. On Windows (using ```nslookup -query=AXFR mydomain.com```), you'll get hit with ```Format error``` or something similar.

Comment: @Anorov underscores are allowed in domain names but not in hostnames. see the relevant RFCs

Comment: Also https://crt.sh/ could give you some subdomains

Answer (score 126):

If you can't get this information from DNS (e.g. you aren't authorized) then one alternative is to use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

1. Enter the domain into the search box and run the search. (E.g. [`stackexchange.com`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=stackexchange.com))

[image: Wolfram - Homepage]

2. In the 3rd section from the top (named "Web statistics for all of stackexchange.com") click **Subdomains**

[image: Wolfram - Subdomains button]

3. In the Subdomains section click **More**

[image: Wolfram - More subdomains button]

You will be able to see a list of sub-domains there. Although I suspect it does not show ALL sub-domains.

Comment: It appears this doesn't work anymore, atleast not as described.

Comment: This worked for me today, listed 6 subdomains of the domain I was interested in.

Comment: it appears only certain domains (like google.com) will offer a [subdomain] option.

Comment: Their subdomain information seems to be taken from Alexa.com, e.g. http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com

Comment: or you could use this website: https://pentest-tools.com/reconnaissance/find-subdomains-of-domain#

Comment: Guys can also check out http://www.similarweb.com/ it gives a list of subdomains of a specific website whose stats you are looking for

Comment: It doesn't find subdomains I know are there for one example I tried.

Comment: Just use google "site:" search and add known domains as negative matches until it stops finding new domains. E.g., After applying this strategy a few times for domain `realtimerendering.com`, my google search looks like this:  `site:realtimerendering.com -"www.realtimerendering.com" -"kesen.realtimerendering.com" -"erich.realtimerendering.com" -"advances.realtimerendering.com"`

Comment: @ahcox you should make this an answer. worked for me

Comment: As of today, it worked for me as well

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me today. :)

Comment: I had the same requirement but no joy with the above.  For me, this did the trick (not guaranteed to be comprehensive; but good enough): https://dnsdumpster.com/.

Comment: This would only work if web servers running on those subdomains were somehow exposed through search engines.

Answer (score 51):

You can use:

```
$ host -l example.com
```

Under the hood, this uses the `AXFR` query mentioned above. You might not be allowed to do this though. In that case, you'll get a `transfer failed` message.

Comment: For Windows users, you can try `nslookup domain.com`. (`host` is [not available on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21520191/3357935))

Answer (score 31):

1. `dig example.com soa`
2. `dig @ns.SOA.example example.com axfr`

Comment: Any suggestion if transfer fails on that?

Comment: Which of course does not work if axfr is disabled.

Answer (score 8):

You can only do this if you are connecting to a DNS server for the domain -and- AXFR is enabled for your IP address. This is the mechanism that secondary systems use to load a zone from the primary. In the old days, this was not restricted, but due to security concerns, most primary name servers have a whitelist of: secondary name servers + a couple special systems.

If the nameserver you are using allows this then you can use dig or nslookup.

For example:

```
#nslookup

>ls example.com
```

NOTE: because nslookup is being deprecated for dig and other newere tools, some versions of nslookup do not support "ls", most notably macOS X's bundled version.

Answer (score 7):

robotex tools which are free will let you do this but they make you enter the ip of the domain first:

1. find out the ip (there's a good ff plugin which does this but I can't post the link cos this is my first post here!)
2. do an ip search on robotex: http://www.robtex.com/ip/
3. in the results page that follows click on the domain you're interested in>
4. you are taken to a page that lists all subdomains + a load of other information such as mail server info

Answer (score 6):

In Windows `nslookup` the command is

```
ls -d example.com > outfile.txt
```

which stores the subdomain list in `outfile.txt`

few domains these days allow this

Comment: ls? Isn't that a *nix command? Shouldn't it be nslookup -d somedomain.com > outfile.txt

Comment: "ls" is a valid command from the nslookup prompt. From a CMD prompt, enter nslookup first, then you can enter ls -d ...... as suggested

Comment: I ran `nslookup` on Windows 10 PowerShell as Admin and then `ls -d somedomain.com > outfile.txt` and got "Unrecognized command".

Answer (score 5):

If the DNS server is configured properly, you won't be able to get the entire domain.  If for some reason is allows zone transfers from any host, you'll have to send it the correct packet to make that request.  I suspect that's what the dig statement you included does.