# Get Cname records with NetDNS or get_dns_record

Tags: php, dns, pear

I'm trying get a list of CNAME records using PHP.

This method used to work when I was hosting the code on my old Windows 7 machine, but I moved it to an Ubuntu machine (similar AMP stack setup), and it no longer returned CNAME records for the `$url`. I uploaded the code to a Windows server and still yet, no CNAME records.

```
$records['cname'] = dns_get_record($url, DNS_CNAME);
```

Not that I'm claiming the OS has much to do with anything, maybe I had something set up a certain way on my old machine that allowed this to work. It currently returns a simple empty array, where as it used to return a list of CNAME records that matched up with what was in my DNS management service. I've read the article here:

[Why wouldn't dns_get_record show CNAMEs when I KNOW they exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111227/why-wouldnt-dns-get-record-show-cnames-when-i-know-they-exist)

and ended up trying to implement the functionality with Pear's NetDns2 Library, with the following code. And still, the `answer` array of the response is empty. Not sure if the problem is the same from get_dns_record to NetDNS2 or if I'm doing something wrong in both cases, but the sites tested surely have CNAME records, including `google.com` and `yahoo.com`.

```
//using Google Name Server
$rslvr = new Net_DNS2_Resolver(array('nameservers' => array('8.8.8.8')));
$records['cname'] = $rslvr->query($url, 'CNAME');
```

Any help is appreciated, the end goal is to be able to obtain a list of CNAME records like I was on my old machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works here with PHP 5.4.9.

The first record (cweiske.de) is no `CNAME` but directly points to an IP address:

```
php > var_dump(dns_get_record('cweiske.de', DNS_CNAME));
array(0) {
}
```

The second is actually a CNAME to the first record:

```
php > var_dump(dns_get_record('www.cweiske.de', DNS_CNAME));
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(5) {
    'host' =>
    string(14) "www.cweiske.de"
    'class' =>
    string(2) "IN"
    'ttl' =>
    int(86400)
    'type' =>
    string(5) "CNAME"
    'target' =>
    string(10) "cweiske.de"
  }
}
```

`dig` shows the same:

```
$ dig cweiske.de
cweiske.de.     577 IN  A   83.169.7.198

$ dig www.cweiske.de
www.cweiske.de.     86397   IN  CNAME   cweiske.de.
cweiske.de.     597 IN  A   83.169.7.198
```

To check if it's your or PHP's problem, use dig or nslookup to test.

Comment: Both of your results show the opposite of what I was expecting. `dns_get_record('domain.com', DNS_CNAME);` should return a list of CNAME records for that domain, including a.domain.com, b.domain.com, and www.domain.com. Basically all you were able to accomplish with both `dns_get_record` and `dig` was confirm that the URL you entered was a CNAME record and needed to be pointed to an A record. Previously, `dns_get_record` worked as I expected when passing DNS_CNAME as the argument - and it still works like this with DNS_MX and DNS_NS.

Comment: there is no way to get a list of all subdomains for a given server. `NS` lists the nameservers for the given domain, `MX` lists the mail servers for the given domain. `A` gives you the IP for the domain, `CNAME` gives you the CNAME "parent" if the domain has one. I think you misunderstand what DNS allows and what not.

Comment: Just imagine what would happen if you asked ".com" for their CNAMEs or their As - and they'd give you all subdomains of .com.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, but I swear it worked before - it seemed like it was returning all of the CName records in the zone that contained the A record. Is there a way I can take a url like `domain.com` and get all of the records from its zone file?

Comment: Not in a normal way without using AXFR. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/131989/282601

Comment: OK, thanks. I see everything a little better now. - My next problem is since my question basically has no correct answer, should I accept your answer, or what?

Comment: The question you asked had an answer; I gave it. It wasn't the question you meant to ask, though :) Thanks for accepting.