# Getting CNAME records

Tags: php, dns, cname

I'm wondering why it's possible for the following website to get CNAME records for various websites:
http://dnskit.dk/
I've been searching for an hour now, and I've not been able to find anything that would enable me to do the same.

I get all other records except SRV records with: 
`$array = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_CNAME);`
But that doesn't work. I've read the following questions
[Get Cname records with NetDNS or get_dns_record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331853/get-cname-records-with-netdns-or-get-dns-record)
 [Why wouldn't dns_get_record show CNAMEs when I KNOW they exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111227/why-wouldnt-dns-get-record-show-cnames-when-i-know-they-exist)

I'm aware that if I prefix the domain with an existing CNAME that I already know about, some info might be found, but I need to get this info from my lookup.
I've created some special cases for formatting the input URL, so things like http:// and https:// is removed from the URL once submitted, unlike other websites that do not allow those protocols to be there, which was the problem that started me working on this.

Comment: What errors are you getting when using `dns_get_record`?

Comment: That site does not get all CNAME records, it wiil jut try to get several most common.

Comment: @DusanBajic So basically it just has some common CNAMEs in an array?

Comment: I have added some random CNAME to my personal domain and it was not found. Whan I added `www`, it appeared.

Comment: @DusanBajic Thank you for testing it. I think I'm just gonna look out for some common CNAMEs and check against an array of those.