# How to find subdomains of domain

Tags: subdomain

I want to get a List of All Sub-Domains of a Domain Name(public domain). 
google.com has subdomains like images.google.com,maps.google.com. I want to find these through code or tool which I can invoke my Java code.

I already tried options like

https://github.com/TheRook/subbrute

https://github.com/guelfoweb/knock

But,They are not accurate.

Any other options available?

Comment: is the top level domain public or private to your own network?

Answer (score 1):

If this is an internal domain to your network it should be easy enough to query your own DNS server, given the appropriate permissions.

If this is a public domain, that will be a little harder - most likely required a brute force approach.

You may want to check out this [Is it possible to find all DNS subdomains for a given domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305495/is-it-possible-to-find-all-dns-subdomains-for-a-given-domain-name)