# Unix command "host" - is there Windows equivalent?

Tags: windows, host

I am on a Windows 7 machine and I was instructed to use the Unix command "host" as per this article:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

however, `host` is not a valid command with Windows and even with bash on Windows I could find `host` installed.

Is there a Windows equivalent to "host"?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This question is more suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com), but the command you're looking for is `nslookup`. Both are (at their most basic) used to look up IP addresses for hostnames. You can run `cmd` and do `nslookup hostname` the same way you'd do `host hostname`. If you need something other than the IP address, the command-line arguments will differ. Run `nslookup` with no arguments and type `help` at the prompt for details.

Comment: @Shane Baker's answer contains a powershell command that returns all aliases and not just one as nslookup most of the times

Answer (score 6):

Although you will be able to find the DNS resolution using `nslooukup`, there is no direct equivalent to the `host` command in Windows. There is a similar question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1016420).

Answer (score 4):

Old thread, but I hit it doing Google searches.  There is no built in but if you add this to your profile.ps1 it'll do what you want.

```
function host {
param ($ip)
$ErrorActionPreference='stop'
$answer=Resolve-DnsName $ip
if ($answer[0].IPAddress -eq $null)
{
    echo "$($answer.Name[0]) has address $($answer.namehost[0])"
}
else
{
    echo "$($answer.Name[0]) has address $($answer.Ipaddress[0])"
}
}
```

Comment: Note that this is a PowerShell command.  Also, the code above only returns the first record found.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command "Nslookup" followed by your business domain to look up its server's IP address. If the server has multiple IP addresses associated with the name, the command will list all of them. As an example, you might enter "nslookup google.com" to find a list of Google's IP addresses.

Answer (score -1):

Use ping -a to replicate the host command.